# RSpec FactoryBot Validation failed many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I keep getting `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Role must exist` when running the below spec.

I'm basically trying to add creators to a song. A credit record is made which is the join table in the database.  Now the credit table also has a column role_id that belongs_to the roles table.  But I can't work out how to create the roles record so that it exist upon adding the creator to a song.  Full breakdown of the code below.

Spec:

```
describe '.get' do
        before :each do 
            @song = create(:song)
            @creator = create(:creator)
            @song.creators << @creator    
        end
end
```

Models:

```
class Credit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :creator
  belongs_to :role 
end


class Song < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :credits
  has_many :creators, through: :credits
end



class Creator < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :credits
    has_many :songs, through: :credits
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryBot.define do 
    factory :song do 
        name { Faker::Music::Phish.song }
        uri {"spotify:track:#{SecureRandom.alphanumeric(22)}"}
        current_popularity {rand(0..100)}
        master {1}
        credits_checked {0}
        credits_verified {0}
        credits_approved {0}
        checked {0}
        created_at {Time.now - rand(3..30).days}
        updated_at {Time.now - 1.days} 
    end
end


FactoryBot.define do 
    factory :creator do 
        name { Faker::Name.name }
        claimed {0}
        created_at {Time.now - rand(10..30).days}
        updated_at {Time.now - rand(1..5).days}
    end
end

FactoryBot.define do
    factory :credit do 
        creator
        song
        role { create(:role) }
        active {1}
        display {1}
        created_at {Time.now - rand(10..30).days}
        updated_at {Time.now - rand(1..5).days}

    end
end

FactoryBot.define do 
    factory :role do 
        name {'Writer'}
        ordering {1}
        created_at {Time.now}
        updated_at {Time.now}
    end
end
```

Comment: What about Role model and corresponding factory? Has it any validation? What means `XXX` in the error? Could you please full error text from your test

Comment: Have added with the correct error text.  Role model is in there it doesn't have any relations defined.  The role factory is now included as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have third `belongs_to` in Credit model, and it is required, you can't use default Rails way `<<` to add associated record. You have two options here:

1. Make role association optional and assign role to credit after creation

   ```
   belongs_to :role, optional: true

   before :each do 
     @role = create(:role)
     @song = create(:song)
     @creator = create(:creator)
     @song.creators << @creator  
     @song.credits.find_by(creator: @creator).update(role: @role)  
   end
   ```
2. Create credit explicitly, without `<<` operator

   ```
   before :each do 
     @role = create(:role)
     @song = create(:song)
     @creator = create(:creator)
     @song.credits.create(creator: @creator, role: @role)  
   end
   ```

I think, the second one it better, because you keep role validation and create credit instance in one operation.